# Partition Frisbees C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, set

We have a set F of n frisbee's in 2D. We want to partition F into two subsets F1, and F2 so that no two frisbee's intersect in each respective subset. Our function takes in input as so: (x_j, y_j) is the centre of the j-th frisbee, and rad_j is the radius of the j-th frisbee. The output should be s_0 s_1 ... s_n-1, where s_j = 1 if the j-th frisbee is in F1 and s_i = 2 if the j-th frisbee is in F2. If you cannot partition F, just return 0. Ideally, the algo should be computed in O(n^2) time.

I figured that I should use some type type of matrix representation of this like graph, but then I don't think I need need to construct a graph, but I think I BFS/DFS would be useful, but I'm stuck on how exactly to do this elegantly in O(n^2). I am coding this in C++ by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on a right track with a graph search.  Here's a C++11, O(V^2), depth first search solution that uses O(V+E) space.

The DFS itself is O(V+E) in time, but generating the adjacency lists is O(V^2) the obvious way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct Frisbee
{
  double x;
  double y;
  double radius;
};

int dfs(const vector< vector<int> > &adj, vector<int> &p, int last_ind, int curr_ind)
{
  if (p[curr_ind])                   // node already painted
  { 
    if (p[last_ind] == p[curr_ind])  // painted same color as neighbor -> failure
      return 0;

    return 1;                        // painting is compatible
  }

  // node not yet painted

  p[curr_ind] = (1 == p[last_ind] ? 2 : 1);        // paint opposite color as neighbor

  for (int j = 0; j < adj[curr_ind].size(); ++j)
    if (!dfs(adj, p, curr_ind, adj[curr_ind][j]))  // dfs on neighbors
      return 0;

  return 1;
}

int partition(const vector<Frisbee> &F, vector<int> &p)
{
  // compute adjacency lists

  vector< vector<int> > adj(F.size());

  p.resize(F.size());

  for (int i = 0; i < F.size(); ++i)
  {
    p[i] = 0;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < F.size(); ++j)
    {
      double dist = sqrt((F[i].x - F[j].x) * (F[i].x - F[j].x) + (F[i].y - F[j].y) * (F[i].y - F[j].y));

      if (dist < F[i].radius + F[j].radius)
      {
        adj[i].push_back(j);
        adj[j].push_back(i);
      }
    }
  }

  // find starting points for dfs

  for (int i = 0; i < F.size(); ++i)
    if (0 == p[i])                       // node i not yet painted
    {      
      p[i] = 1;                          // arbitrarily choose initial color

      for (int j = 0; j < adj[i].size(); ++j)
        if (!dfs(adj, p, i, adj[i][j]))  // dfs on neighbors
          return 0;
    }

  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vector<Frisbee> F = { { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }, { 2.0, 2.0, 1.0 }, { -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 }, { -2.0, -2.0, 1.0 }, { 5.0, 5.0, 1.0 }, { -5.0, 5.0, 1.0 } };
  vector<int>     p;

  if (partition(F, p))
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < F.size(); ++i)
      cout << p[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
  }
  else
    cout << "No partition possible!" << endl;

  F.push_back({ 1.5, 1.5, 1.0 });  // add a 3-way intersection

  if (partition(F, p))
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < F.size(); ++i)
      cout << p[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
  }
  else
    cout << "No partition possible!" << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output (of two partitions on slightly different sets of Frisbee's):

```
1 2 1 2 1 1 
No partition possible!
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you just do a stacked for-loop and use the distance formula? i.e. two intersect if the distance between their centres is smaller than the sum of their radii.

After that, you've state-exploded it and then you can proceed to just do loop inclusion/exclusion (i.e. include everything and get rid of all invalid ones and then include as many valid ones etc.)

Comment: I still don't get it. What do you mean by state-exploded? I had this as an interview question, but I messed it up. So now I am just trying to code it on my own. Do you have an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a graph where an edge means "touches". Then you can use a bipartition algorithm on that graph. Boost.Graph contains one.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/is_bipartite.html

The algorithm is O(V+E), i.e. worst case O(V^2) if all discs touch each other (although there's a good chance it will abort early in that case).

Building the graph naively is O(V^2), since you have to check each disc against all others, although you might be able to optimize the common case by building a geographical quad tree to sort the discs first.